# How to set the initialValue of the trendLine as the max value of Value Axis in AmCharts?

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I'm using AmCharts to populate my data. I'm displaying trend lines in my chart. Is there any way to set the max value of the Value Axis as the `initialValue` of the trendiine ?

```
var trendLines = [{
  "initialValue": 1800,
  "initialCategory": 1997,
  "lineColor": "#050",
  "lineThickness": 1,
  "dashLength": 5
  "finalValue": 0,
  "finalCategory": 1997
}
```

Here is a [code pen demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XpZvwP) with static values in `initialValue`

Comment: I believe the easiest way to do so would be to set a "maximum" property to your value axis, and have the same value as the "initialValue" for your trendline.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a static/hard-coded `minimum` and `maximum` in your value axis, you could do what Robbert mentioned in the comments. If you want to dynamically set it, you can use the [`init`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmChart#init) event to access the valueAxis' read-only [`min`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis#min) and [`max`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis#max) properties, which correspond to the calculated minimums and maximums of the valueAxis and add/set the trendline(s) there. Here's an example of creating a new trendline that goes from the first category and maximum value, to the last category and minimum value:

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  //other settings omitted
  "listeners": [{
    "event": "init",
    "method": function(e) {
      var trendline = {
        "initialValue": e.chart.valueAxes[0].max, //max axis value
        "finalValue": e.chart.valueAxes[0].min,  //min axis value
        "initialCategory": e.chart.dataProvider[0][e.chart.categoryField],
        "finalCategory":e.chart.dataProvider[e.chart.dataProvider.length - 1][e.chart.categoryField]
      };
      e.chart.trendLines.push(trendline);
      e.chart.validateNow();
    }
  }]
});
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/b6d30536b00149e5519dd905be584f94/?editors=0010)